# Javascript/jQuery connect four with flaws

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm probably the 10k guy on the internet who needs help on a connect-four game, but still, I hope someone out their might be patient enough to help me. Sure, I looked into various threads by now, but this wasn't really solving my problem.
I have to create my own connect-four game in javascript without using let and const variables, since they have not been taught to my class by now.

I have issues to track the diagonal winner. Yet, my code seams to have an issue with the scope I run various functions in, too.

Anyone an idea, how to get my diagonal winner?

```js
//IIFE
(function() {
    // var row/columns declared with values
    this.numberOfRows = 6;
    this.numberOfCols = 7;
    // var currentPlayer declared with value of player1
    var currentPlayer = "player1";
    // var gameOver declared with a value of false in order to give a value true
    // when a winner is found
    var gameOver = false;
    // evenhandler recognizing a click in the columns declared executing a function(event)
    $(".column").on("click", function(event) {
        // var slotsInColumn declared = $event in the DOMs bubbling phase which finds the
        // descendants of the elements passed in before -> in the slots
        var slotsInColumn = $(event.currentTarget).find(".slot");
        // slots in rows equal to <div(s)> in the html
        var slotsInRow0 = $(".row0");
        var slotsInRow1 = $(".row1");
        var slotsInRow2 = $(".row2");
        var slotsInRow3 = $(".row3");
        var slotsInRow4 = $(".row4");
        var slotsInRow5 = $(".row5");
        var rows = [
            slotsInRow0,
            slotsInRow1,
            slotsInRow2,
            slotsInRow3,
            slotsInRow4,
            slotsInRow5
        ];
        // loop iterating over the array from 5 to 0 until their is no space available
        // in the columns for new coins to be inserted
        for (var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
            // slot in column is assigned to a player; value passed into newly created
            // jquery obj(i)
            if (
                !slotsInColumn.eq(i).hasClass("player1") &&
                !slotsInColumn.eq(i).hasClass("player2")
            ) {
                // function stops if the above is the case
                break;
            }
        }
        // free slot will be assigned to current the player
        slotsInColumn.eq(i).addClass(currentPlayer);

        if (
            verticalVictory(cols) ||
            horizoVictory(rows) ||
            // diagonalVictoryBottomLeftToTopRight() ||
            // diagonalVictoryTopLeftToBottomRight()
        ) {
        } else {
            if (curPlayer == "player1") {
                // console.log('changing to 2');
                curPlayer = "player2";
            } else if (curPlayer == "player2") {
                // console.log('changing back to 1');
                curPlayer = "player1";
            }
        }
    });

    // function checkForVictory declared with slots as an argument to be passed in
    function verticalVictory(slots) {
        // var string equal to an empty string
        var string = "";
        // for loop iterating over the slots
        for (var i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
            // if slots in the index are assigned(hasClass) to the current Player
            if (slots.eq(i).hasClass(currentPlayer)) {
                // addition assignment operator (+=) adds the value "Victory!" to the string
                string += "Victory!";
            } else {
                // addition assignment operator (+=) adds the value "Error!" to the string
                string += "Error!";
            }
        }
        // returns
        return string.indexOf("vvv") > -1;
    }

    // function checkForVictory declared with slots as an argument to be passed in
    function horizontalVictory(slots) {
        // var string equal to an empty string
        var string = "";
        // for loop iterating over the slots
        var horizontalVictory = slots[i];
        for (var i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < horizontalVictory.length; i++) {
                // if slots in the index are assigned(hasClass) to the current Player
                if (horizontalVictory.eq(j).hasClass(currentPlayer)) {
                    // addition assignment operator (+=) adds the value "Victory!" to the string
                    string += "Victory!";
                } else {
                    // addition assignment operator (+=) adds the value "Error!" to the string
                    string += "Error!";
                }
            }
        }
        // returns
        return string.indexOf("vvv") > -1;
    }

    function checkDirection(direction) {
        // increment in the direction that the color is equal to the number we
        // are looking for
        var total = 0;
        var i = row + direction.i;
        var j = col + direction.j;
        while (
            i >= 0 &&
            i < this.numberOfRows &&
            j >= 0 &&
            j < this.numberOfCols &&
            $next.data("player") === that.player
        ) {
            total++;
            i += direction.i;
            j += direction.j;
        }

        function checkWinner(directionA, directionB) {
            var total =
                1 + checkDirection(directionA) + checkDirection(directionB);
            if (total >= 4) {
                return that.player;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // check from bottom left to top right
        function diagonalVictoryBottomLeftToTopRight() {
            return checkWinner({ i: 1, j: -1 }, { i: 1, j: 1 });
        }

        // check from top left to bottom right
        function diagonalVictoryTopLeftToBottomRight() {
            return checkWinner({ i: 1, j: 1 }, { i: -1, j: -1 });
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.column {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

.slot {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
}

.hole {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: white;
}

.slot.player1 .hole {
    background-color: red;
}

.slot.player2 .hole {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="slot row0">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row1">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row2">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row3">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row4">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row5">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="slot row0">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row1">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row2">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row3">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row4">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row5">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="slot row0">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row1">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row2">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row3">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row4">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row5">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="slot row0">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row1">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row2">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row3">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row4">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row5">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="slot row0">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row1">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row2">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row3">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row4">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row5">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="slot row0">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row1">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row2">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row3">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row4">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row5">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="slot row0">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row1">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row2">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row3">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row4">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot row5">
                <div class="hole"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should happen, what happens instead? What "issues"? Any error messages in the console? Any further observations? What have you done to figure the problem out yourself? ...?

Comment: I must be blind...I don't see any arrays...?

Comment: @ zer00ne: I added the arrays in the .js file as a variable rows

Comment: This?: `slotsInRow0 = $(".row0");` no that's just a jQuery Object (a jQuery Collection to be more precise.) Anyways this is totally fubared:  `if (
            verticalVictory(cols) ||
            horizoVictory(rows) ||
        ) {
        } else {
            if (curPlayer == "player1") {
                 curPlayer = "player2";
            } else if (curPlayer == "player2") {

                curPlayer = "player1";
            }
        }`

Comment: If you had true arrays inside that outer array then you can use `unshift()` on any of the columns or better yet the `Map()` object would work perfectly but it's ES6 you haven't learned it yet. Anyways, it's gong to be hard to get help unless you take Andreas's advice.

Comment: You both are right, gonna do my homework and explain the problems I ran into better in the future

Comment: Run your JS at http://jshint.com/ Make sure to click the CONFIGURE link at the top right and then pick the `jQuery` option. Good luck, sir.